# Python value error json

Tags: python, json, keyerror

I am getting the following error for the following code and I am not able to solve the error. The error occures after the loop has created some files correctly.

I am using the following code:

```
import urllib
import json

symbolslist = open("C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Python/web scraper/scraping/symbols.txt").read()
symbolslist = [s for s in symbolslist.split("\n") if s]

for symbol in symbolslist:
    myfile = open("C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Python/web scraper/scraping/year_data/" + symbol +".txt" , "w+")
    myfile.close()
    htmltext = urllib.urlopen("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/"+symbol+"%3AUS?timeFrame=1_YEAR")
    data = json.load(htmltext)
    try:
        datapoints = data[0]["price"]
    except KeyError:
        print 'Unknown symbol: {0}'.format(symbol)
        continue
    myfile = open("C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Python/web scraper/scraping/year_data/" + symbol +".txt" , "a")
    for point in datapoints:
        myfile.write(str(symbol +","+ str(point['date']) +","+ str(point['value'])+"\n"))
    myfile.close()
```

A symbol is for example AAPL (for Apple) and this is the link to bloomberg data for Apple:
http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/AAPL%3AUS?timeFrame=1_YEAR

This is the `data`:

```
[{u'lastPrice': 10.18, u'price': [{u'date': u'2014-12-26', u'value': 10.01}, {u'date': u'2014-12-30', u'value': 10.01}, {u'date': u'2015-01-07', u'value': 10}, {u'date': u'2015-01-09', u'value': 9.97}, {u'date': u'2015-01-12', u'value': 10}, {u'date': u'2015-01-13', u'value': 10.02}, {u'date': u'2015-01-14', u'value': 10.04}, {u'date': u'2015-01-16', u'value': 10.1}, {u'date': u'2015-01-20', u'value': 10.39}, {u'date': u'2015-01-21', u'value': 9.98}, {u'date': u'2015-01-22', u'value': 9.98}, {u'date': u'2015-01-23', u'value': 9.98}, {u'date': u'2015-01-26', u'value': 10.08}, {u'date': u'2015-01-27', u'value': 10.05}, {u'date': u'2015-01-29', u'value': 10.02}, {u'date': u'2015-02-02', u'value': 10.08}, {u'date': u'2015-02-06', u'value': 9.98}, {u'date': u'2015-02-09', u'value': 9.97}, {u'date': u'2015-03-06', u'value': 10.07}, {u'date': u'2015-03-10', u'value': 10.1}, {u'date': u'2015-03-25', u'value': 10.3}, {u'date': u'2015-03-26', u'value': 10.01}, {u'date': u'2015-03-27', u'value': 10.02}, {u'date': u'2015-03-30', u'value': 10.02}, {u'date': u'2015-03-31', u'value': 10.02}, {u'date': u'2015-04-01', u'value': 10.02}, {u'date': u'2015-04-02', u'value': 10.19}, {u'date': u'2015-04-10', u'value': 10.3}, {u'date': u'2015-04-17', u'value': 10.4}, {u'date': u'2015-05-01', u'value': 10.39}, {u'date': u'2015-05-07', u'value': 10.35}, {u'date': u'2015-05-08', u'value': 10.35}, {u'date': u'2015-05-14', u'value': 10.28}, {u'date': u'2015-06-10', u'value': 10.15}, {u'date': u'2015-06-16', u'value': 10.34}, {u'date': u'2015-06-25', u'value': 10.3}, {u'date': u'2015-06-29', u'value': 10.27}, {u'date': u'2015-07-07', u'value': 10.3599}, {u'date': u'2015-07-08', u'value': 10.36}, {u'date': u'2015-07-15', u'value': 10.37}, {u'date': u'2015-07-30', u'value': 10.27}, {u'date': u'2015-08-13', u'value': 10.1}, {u'date': u'2015-08-14', u'value': 10.1}, {u'date': u'2015-08-24', u'value': 10.14}, {u'date': u'2015-08-25', u'value': 10.14}, {u'date': u'2015-08-27', u'value': 10.17}, {u'date': u'2015-08-31', u'value': 10.2}, {u'date': u'2015-09-01', u'value': 10.25}, {u'date': u'2015-09-03', u'value': 10.24}, {u'date': u'2015-09-04', u'value': 10.35}, {u'date': u'2015-09-15', u'value': 10.2401}, {u'date': u'2015-09-21', u'value': 10.22}, {u'date': u'2015-09-22', u'value': 10.22}, {u'date': u'2015-09-28', u'value': 10.2933}, {u'date': u'2015-10-02', u'value': 10.4}, {u'date': u'2015-10-06', u'value': 10.44}, {u'date': u'2015-10-12', u'value': 10.22}, {u'date': u'2015-10-13', u'value': 10.21}, {u'date': u'2015-10-22', u'value': 10.25}, {u'date': u'2015-10-28', u'value': 10.15}, {u'date': u'2015-11-04', u'value': 10.15}, {u'date': u'2015-12-09', u'value': 10}, {u'date': u'2015-12-16', u'value': 10.18}], u'priceMinDecimals': 2, u'nyTradeEndTime': u'16:30:00.000', u'lastUpdateDate': u'2015-12-16', u'nyTradeStartTime': u'09:30:00.000', u'id': u'TFSCU:US', u'timeZoneOffset': -5, u'dateTimeRanges': {}}]
```

The problem I found is that there exists no data for some symbols, that means the data shown on the URL is: `{u'securityType': u'UNKNOWN'}`. This occures for example for following `symbols`: `AGNCB, AGNCP, MTGEP, ASRVP, AMSGP, AGIIL, ARWAU, BANFP, BKEPP, BPFHP, BBEPP`. 
The Problem still is how I can exclude missing data, without interrupting the loop? And why do I get an ValueError after the loop correctly has created 440 files?

The current Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
execfile("C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Python\web scraper\scraping\stock_to_file.py")
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Python\web scraper\scraping\stock_to_file.py", line 11, in <module>
data = json.load(htmltext)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 291, in load
**kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: What does `data` look like if you print it?

Comment: it means data[0] has no "0" key. you could try to use except to catch it then continue your loop. it may cause by the stock has no valid data in Bloomberg. simply log out when you get exception then you will found out why

Comment: @Pedram I wonder if this can help you: [bloomberg_api](https://github.com/bpsmith/tia)

Comment: When I go to the [bloomberg url](http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/APL%3AUS?timeFrame=1_YEAR) in the code, the json object does look like it should be indexable by zero. Maybe there's some kind of rate-limiting mechanism that makes it return nothing if you visit the page too frequently?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, this could be it. But how can I avoid this?

Comment: Well there's not much point in discussing solutions to rate-limiting since we still don't know if that's the problem. I would really like to see `data` to see if it sheds any light.

Comment: @Kevin there you go. I edited the Question. You can see the `data` at the bottom

Comment: That's strange, I can index that data just fine [on my machine](http://ideone.com/oWoroO). Are you 100% sure that this is the data that's causing the exception?

Comment: @Kevin yes as I mentioned the error occures after the loop has created some files correctly and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Put the `datapoints = ...` line in a `try` block with an `except KeyError: print data`, and see if that's really what the data looks like at the point when the exception is raised.

Comment: @glibdud It worked better now. It printed this: `{u'securityType': u'UNKNOWN'}` and gave this error `raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded") ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416541/python-key-error-json?noredirect=1#comment56576428_34416541), the response you're getting from Bloomberg is:

```
{u'securityType': u'UNKNOWN'}
```

Bloomberg will return this if it doesn't recognize the symbol you're requesting. If you want to identify the bad symbols and continue with the script for the good ones, you can do one of:

**1. Detect the error response, take any desired action, and move to the next (LBYL)**

```
data = json.load(htmltext)
if u'securityType' in data and data[u'securityType'] == u'UNKNOWN':
    print 'Unknown symbol: {0}'.format(symbol)
    continue
```

**2. Go ahead with the processing and capture the exception (EAFP)**

```
try:
    datapoints = data[0]["price"]
except KeyError:
    print 'Unknown symbol: {0}'.format(symbol)
    continue
```

It's a stylistic choice. In either case, the important thing is to `continue` to go to the next symbol once you detect the bad response.

Comment: There is no blank line in the .txt, but the problem I found is that there exists no data for some `symbols`, that means the data shown on the URL is: `{u'securityType': u'UNKNOWN'}`. This occures for example for following `symbols`: `AGNCB, AGNCP, MTGEP, ASRVP, AMSGP, AGIIL, ARWAU, BANFP, BKEPP, BPFHP, BBEPP`. The Problem still is how I can exclude missing data, without interrupting the loop? And why do I get an ValueError after the loop correctly has created 440 files?

Comment: @PedramShahlaifar Did you try my suggestion? Even if you don't see any blank lines, the last line of the file could end with a newline, which would cause `split` to add an extra `''` to the end of the list.

Comment: of course I tried your suggestion. Same error. I think the problem is that the delivered data varies. And there may be some comma too much or something in the data.

Comment: @PedramShahlaifar Ok, then it looks like it doesn't like the symbols you're trying to check. I got that error from the first two in your list; I didn't go farther. Will update my answer for the newer question.

Comment: @PedramShahlaifar Updated. You might want to edit the symbols list in your above comment into the question, as they're a critical part of why your code didn't work.

Comment: I updated the question and the code, the value error still exists.

Comment: @PedramShahlaifar You now have an error in the `json.load` line. Now you need to know what the value of `htmltext` is at that point. The same troubleshooting procedures can be used.

Comment: you are the best! I am quite new to python so thx for your patience. Could you update your troubleshooting answer? So everyone knows what to do in these cases?